# How to get count of currently running EC2 Resource of a particular region

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to list all the resource available in a region.

Currently am implementing this by calling the individual functions and taking the count but that is time consuming is there any single function call that returns all these count values.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'calling the individual functions'?

By looking at [the API Docs for DescribeInstances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html), it looks clearly straightforward: No arguments, and you'll get all the instances (once you iterate over all the reservations, of course).

What you can do to improve performance is to apply a filter. If you know, for instance, the AMI Id of the instances you'd like to count, you could pass it as a resource.